# Episerver/CMS & Dojo/Aspect– how to catch revert to publish event in Dojo?

Tags: dojo, episerver

In post [Event on "Revert to Published"](https://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/-Episerver-75-CMS/Thread-Container/2014/4/Event-on-Revert-to-Published/) I found code to "attach" to revertToPublished event.

```js
dojo.require(["dojo/aspect", "epi/dependency"], function(aspect, dependencey) {
    var editingCommands = dependency.resolve("epi.cms.contentEditing.command.Editing");
    aspect.before(editingCommands.revertToPublished, "_execute", function() {
        // TODO: Reverting Content To Published
    });
});
```

Basically the code is proper and should work but at least in my widget if I set up this in

```js
postCreate: function () {}
```

does not so the advise method is never called. Neither **before** nor **after** method registration works. The **around** registration works and calls immediately ([as it should](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/aspect.html#around)).

I’m missing something specific, I guess. Sufficient solution is also to be able to check that model is freshly loaded so no property has tracked change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code bellow serves the purpose.

```js
aspect.before(
  dependency.resolve("epi.cms.contentEditing.command.Editing").model,
  "revertToPublished",
  function() {});
```